# Alternative to material table

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js, material-table

I'm using NextJS and Tailwind. Since NextJS uses react v.18 npm Material Table is no longer supported. I used to use it all the time when I was using React v.16. Is there an alternative npm install that is compatible with React v.18? I'd like something that has similar functionality like being able to export the table to an excel file.

Comment: There is no harm in using `material-table`, as it is backwards compatible. You'll further get updates in `material-table` which will make it compatible with react v.18

Comment: material-table isn't compatible with React v18 which is what Nextjs runs